# UIPickerView Causes Application To Crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipickerview

I have two views.
First : FirstViewController
Second: SecondViewController

FirstView Controller is my UINavigationController's root controller and I have a table in it. When a cell is clicked view is navigated to SecondViewController. In SecondViewController I am trying to put a UIPickerView.

In SecondViewController.h, I have:

```
@interface SearchOptionController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *optionArray;

}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *optionArray;

@end
```

In SecondViewController.m i have:

```
@synthesize pickerView;
```

and all pickerview methods.

I added UIPickerView from the interface builder and selected File's Owner for Delegate and Data Source. But when the ViewDidLoad method ends in SecondViewController the application crashes saying:

> Program received signal: SIGABRT

at second line of:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

What am i supposed to do to prevent this crash and let the view load with uipickerview?

Edit:

When I remove the UIPickerView from Interface Builder, application runs correctly. I guess I have some problem with putting UIPickerView inside UIView, but i could not handle, being newbie is hard .s

Comment: when application crashes you normally see error description in console - what is it?

Comment: have you implemented delegate methods of picker?

Comment: 2011-05-12 16:04:55.108 Senior5[1006:207] -[SearchOptionController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e33410
2011-05-12 16:04:55.110 Senior5[1006:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SearchOptionController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e33410'

Comment: Ok i found the problem 
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
method was missing. Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have implemented the delegate methods for this object.